# WinAPI Combo Box Issue - Skipped by case

Tags: c, winforms, winapi, combobox

Hi all I wonder if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong I have made a dialog application and all its done apart from one problem which is my combo boxes I have added these to tab page and they are called by the handler below. My problem is where to add the combo box fields i.e

```
   // Sets up the combo box menu 
   HWND hwndComboTab = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_COMBO1);
   ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 1");
   ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 2");
   ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 3");
```

I assumed it would be under WM_INITDIALOG but I always get a case skipped error. I assume it would need to be inside

case 1: for example is this correct? and if so what varriables are posted to this section a bool?

Also I tryed adding it before the switch statesments and it works but the options panel is replicaed many times giving me spammed options.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyTabDialogOne(HWND hwndDlg,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) 
{ 

   // Switches the message for tab 1 control
    switch (uMsg) 
    { 
    case WM_INITDIALOG: // Tryed here case error
        break; 
    case WM_COMMAND:      
        { 
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) // No point here as this is after a button is clicked
            { 
    case IDC_GET_CODE: // Handles the GET Code button in tab
// Displays the result to main window
HWND hwndEdit2 = GetDlgItem(GetParent(GetParent(hwndDlg)), IDC_OUTPUT);
SetWindowText(hwndEdit2,buffer);
// Displays the result to bottom bar
HWND hwndStatic1 = GetDlgItem(GetParent(GetParent(hwndDlg)), IDC_STATIC1); 
Static_SetText(hwndStatic1, "Completed");
//MessageBox(hwndDlg,TEXT("Selected"),TEXT("Button"),0); 
            break; 
            } 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return FALSE ; 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you tried to put it in `WM_INITDIALOG`, you made the common mistake of not putting braces around the block:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK MyTabDialogOne(HWND hwndDlg,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) 
{ 

   // Switches the message for tab 1 control
    switch (uMsg) 
    { 
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND hwndComboTab = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_COMBO1);
            ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 1");
            ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 2");
            ComboBox_AddString(hwndComboTab, "Option 3");
            break; 
        }
    case WM_COMMAND:      
        { 
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) // No point here as this is after a button is clicked
            { 
                case IDC_GET_CODE: // Handles the GET Code button in tab
                    {
                        // Displays the result to main window
                        HWND hwndEdit2 = GetDlgItem(GetParent(GetParent(hwndDlg)), IDC_OUTPUT);
                        HWND hwndStatic1 = GetDlgItem(GetParent(GetParent(hwndDlg)), IDC_STATIC1); 
                        SetWindowText(hwndEdit2,buffer);
                        // Displays the result to bottom bar
                        Static_SetText(hwndStatic1, "Completed");
                        //MessageBox(hwndDlg,TEXT("Selected"),TEXT("Button"),0); 
                        break; 
                    }
                default:
                    return FALSE;
            } 
            break; 
        } 
    default:
        return FALSE; 
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Not adding the braces causes the declaration of `hwndComboTab` to be skipped. I've also sorted out your return statements. If you handled a message, you should return `TRUE`, else `FALSE`. This is with exception to a few messages as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

One last thing I did was to move your declarations to the start of each scope. I assume your file is `.cpp` even though you appear to be coding C. If your extension was `.c`, VC++ would treat the file as a C source and the way you are doing your declarations would not even compile.